# python - convert binary data to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

```
_f = open("c:/go-next.png", "rb")
data = _f.read()
_f.close()
data.encode("utf-8")

# Error: UnicodeDecodeError: file <maya console> line 1: ascii #
```

As you see I open a image file, and the data is  type. But I have to convert it to utf-8.
Maybe binary data has some extra char (or not), it conflict with conversion. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I don't mean to be blunt, but converting a PNG to UTF8 doesn't make any sense.  PNG is an image format.  UTF8 is a text encoding.  Can you explain more what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I try to POST my data to SERVER within HTTP. To do that, I refer to [http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/#uploading-files](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/#uploading-files) and make it well. But, to POST special character (like Korean), I have to send it in "UTF-8" format. Server administrator tell me to do that :)

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim using code in that link, you would `add_file` for the image, and `add_field` for text. `.add_file("my_image", "go-next.png",  open("c:/go-next.png", "rb"), "image/png")` and for text `.add_field("key", "text")`

Comment: Please see timeartist answer. To convert binary data to `utf-8` (which is an encoding for text) you need a format in between. For example, using base64:

`file_data_b64 = b64encode(file_data).decode('utf-8')`

And then you can get back to the binary format when you save the file to avoid data loss:

`a_file.write(b64decode(file_data))`

Decoding with another text encoding , like `latin-1`, before encoding to `utf-8` is dangerous because not every binary file (for example, PNG) would be suitable for text encoding (probably `data.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")` is NOT what you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text encodings only apply to text. Do not attempt to use them on binary data.

Comment: Yes, I and my colleague set up another POST module.

Comment: b'DRIVES STORE TEXT AS BYTES'.decode ('utf8')

Answer (score 7):

You can always map a `str` to `unicode` using the `latin-1` codec. Once you have a `unicode`, you can always encode it in `utf-8`:

```
data.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: While this is true, the result has no meaning.

Comment: Without meaning? A supercomputer was once asked, "What is the meaning of life?" I'm pretty sure it answered, `'42'.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')`. :-)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
The `latin-1` codec maps codepoints "0-255 to the bytes 0x0-0xff":
https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode
So, this does exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: @yingted: I'm *pretty* sure that converting 0xd0 to 0xc3 0x90 atc. will corrupt the image, which is hardly what you'd want.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just hit this. I have to transfer a blob across a UTF-8 channel, but I don't have a base64 decoder on the receiving side. This would be the correct answer if the question made any sense.

Comment: @unutbu i was really struggling to solve an error and your comment gave me a good laugh :D

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to accomplish can probably be achieved by base64 encoding it.

```
 import base64
 encoded = base64.b64encode(image_binary_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Image cannot be converted into something like charters in utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding means converting strings to storable bytes.
And Decoding means converting bytes to readable strings.

The `data` in your code is already encoded.