# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 3: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, decoding

I am using `repl.it` Python web IDE, and I really can't solve a problem with it.

I was trying to decode a string, but it seems that there's no way to do it.

```
import base64

ciphertext = 'FxM7o1wl/7wE9CHPNzbB944feDFXbTSVaJfaLsUMzH5EP4xZRz7Sq8O3y7+jPbXIMVRxpvJZZm7ugqQ4fwpJwtvnB0/BoU+hhGeEZZZ0fFj1irm/zg3bsxOoxBJx4B3U'

ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)

print ciphertext
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 3: invalid start byte

Comment: Based on your variable name `ciphertext`, I'd guess that your string is still encrypted somehow. You need to decrypt it before you try to print it. If you're just trying to see the intermediate results use `print repr(cipertext)`.

Comment: Have you copy-pasted the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *print* `ciphertext`, since it is a sequence of nonsensical binary bytes, *not* a text at all (I checked).

Your terminal is assuming that if you print something, that something is UTF8; and [it is not. Hence the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743127/python-convert-binary-data-to-utf-8). If you had a ciphertext of `VGhpcyB3aWxsIGJlIHByaW50ZWQuCg==`, that would be printed without problems, since it decodes to valid UTF-8 (valid ASCII-7 actually).

If you want to display the ciphertext, you can replace non-UTF8 characters with spaces, or you can print the ciphertext as hex.

But, actually, what you should really do is decrypt it before printing (also, when you've done it, verify it is a UTF8 text and not, say, encoded in ISO-8859-15 or other charsets. If it is, you can use the appropriate codec; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8) also supplies useful information on charsets).

Comment: Any idea on how to decrypt it ?

Comment: It's a 96 binary bytes (thus 768 bits) sequence, apparently random. It might be a **lot** of things, but as ciphers go, I'd go out on a limb and bet on Rijndael cipher. Which, without the encryption key, can't realistically be broken.

Comment: Actually i have the key, thats it: fbc8b03597d6ccc89ac9f823

Comment: 12 bytes, hex encoded. That's strange, and does not look like Rijndael/AES (should be 16). There are other ciphers with key size of 8. I'll look into it tonight.

Comment: mmm, you are right. Ive searched for any ROT variant but i am really not sure about that. We can maybe work together ?

Comment: @L.Fain: Rather than guessing (and when it comes to encryption, you can't really guess), why not go to the source where the encoded string is coming from and ask them how it is encoded?