# Problem decoding £ sign from Python serial input

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using a SIM7100 module in a project which has a SIM card in it.
I can send and receive texts with no problem until I send an AT+USD command to request the current balance on the SIM.
If I use minicom to send the command, I get a (correct) response:

AT+CUSD: 0,"O2: Your balance is £10.84"

I'm using 'import serial' at the start of the program.
When I send the same message via Python program, and try to read the answer, I get a decode error when the string has got as far as the '£' sign:

'can't decode byte Oxa3 in position 0. Invalid start byte.'

I've tried to decode in 2 ways, using code as follows:

```
while port.inWaiting()>0:
response+=str(port.read(1).decode())
```

and also:

```
while port.inWaiting()>0:
response+=str(port.read(1).decode(utf-8))
```

Neither method works and the error is the same. I don't know how to find what encoding method is used by the SIM7100 and I don't know any other options to try. 
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The stream is encoded as latin-1, so decode from latin-1 like this:

```
port.read(1).decode('latin-1')
```

**Edit:**

'£' encoded as latin-1 (and some other 8-bit encodings such as cp1252) is `b'\xa3'`, whereas as 'uf-8' it is `b'\xc2\xa3'`.  If the stream is encoded as UTF-8 then building a response by reading one byte at a time and decoding will not work if the stream contains a character that is encoded as more than one byte.  In this case the best approach would be to collect all the bytes before decoding:

```
response = b''
while port.inWaiting()>0:
    response += port.read(1)
response = response.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This gives the same result.

Comment: @DavidWigg if you still get an error, please add the raw bytes that you receive to your question  (should be something like `b'AT+CUSD: 0,"O2: Your balance is \xc2\xa310.84"'`).

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer should be similar enough to your case:

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 3: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369222/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa3-in-position-3-invalid-s)

As suggested there, to print characters such as 0xa3, either convert them to white spaces or decrypt them.

Comment: I don't know how to convert or decrypt them yet. I'll go digging for answers .

Comment: If the £ character is 2 bytes, do I have to read the serial port in 2 char steps so I get the whole thing in one go? I'm lost as to next steps now.

Answer (score 0):

I added some code to print whatever was received one character at a time and got a complete string including the problem '£'.
After some head scratching, I realised that the response to the AT+CUSD command comes in 2 parts, the first is just 'OK', then, a couple of seconds later, the full response:
AT+CUSD=1, etc... 
The decoding resulted in 'Your balance is £20.74' printing as:

Your balance is 2
59
0.74

I realised this was a decoding issue and used latin-1 decoding. I then added a 4 second delay in reading from the buffer if the command was 'AT+CUSD' and Hey Presto! Problem solved.
Thanks to all those who provided clues and helpful suggestions/information.